# Why do some of my classnames come back as "<>c" with the new VS 2015 compilers?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, visual-studio-2015

We have a bunch of EF Migration classes that are executed in our integration tests. For some of the tests, we find the migration classes using reflection:

```
var dbMigrationClasses = migrationsAssembly.GetTypes()
                         .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbMigration)));
```

We then use the .Name property in some tests:

```
var migrationsWithInvalidClassNames = migrationClasses
                                      .Where(mt => !IsValidMigrationClassName(mt.Name));
```

However, since upgrading to VS 2015 RC, many of our classes report their names as "<>c", and the FullName ends with that too:

```
Name = "<>c"
FullName = "DataMigrations.Migrations._20150121090200_DoSomeStuff+<>c"
```

This never used to happen (I'm guessing it's VS 2015s new compilers that caused it), and it only happens with some (maybe a quarter) of our migration classes. All the classes appear to be the same (all internal, same methods/attributes).

I could handle this by reading FullName and stripping it off, but I'd love to know what's going on and why it's only affecting some classes. Here's two example classes, one comes through fine, one as `<>c`. All I've removed is the SQL inside them:

```
// File 1
namespace NewMind.DMS.DataMigrations.Migrations
{
    [MigrationName("Drop the SavedSearchJSON column from the SavedSearch table.")]
    internal class _20150121143400_DropTheSavedSearchJSONColumnFromTheSavedSearchTable : DmsMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql(@"(SNIP)");
        }
    }
}

// File 2
namespace NewMind.DMS.DataMigrations.Migrations
{
    [MigrationName("Update Facility Key data type as it was incorrectly smallint in some databases.")]
    internal class _20150424130800_StandardiseFacilityKeyDataType : DmsMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Sql(@"(SNIP)");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes; Roslyn changed a bunch of things about how the compiler generates closure classes.  I would guess that this comes from a lambda.  Can you share a concrete class that generates this?

Comment: Are they partial or inherited?

Comment: See my answer... Turned out to be user error. The classes in question actually do have lambdas in them, the new compilers are generating classes that weren't there before, and the assumptions in our code (no non-migration classes in this namespace) are no longer valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is user error :

I actually missed an important line in our code... We find migration classes in two ways... The base class, and namespace:

```
// Get all possible migration classes (use base class + namespace)
var dbMigrationClasses = migrationsAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(DbMigration)));
var migrationNamespaceClasses = migrationsAssembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Migrations", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// Join them together for tests to query
migrationClasses = dbMigrationClasses.Union(migrationNamespaceClasses);
```

This means we're picking up compiler-generated classes from the new compiler *in addition to* the actual classes.

And why I didn't see any difference in the files? I mis-read the classname, and picked a similar migration next to it. Guess what the correct one has in it?...

```
AddColumn("SavedSearch", "SavedSearchXML", c => c.String(nullable: false, defaultValue: "", isMaxLength: true));
```

Doh.

Comment: Hmm, is the argument to `AddColumn` an `Expression`? Perhaps this is finally a compile-time support for constant expressions? In the old compiler, expression trees were always constructed from scratch at runtime. Can you find out some more information about that `<>c` class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `FullName` - the `_20150121090200_DoSomeStuff` part is simply the "parent" class. `<>c` is nested in `_20150121090200_DoSomeStuff`. So to get the name of the nested class and its parent you can just do this:

```
public static string GetAnonymousName(this Type type)
{
  if (!type.IsNested) return type.Name;

  return type.DeclaringType.GetAnonymousName() + "+" + type.Name;
}
```

I don't think it changed in VS2015. Maybe you're using a newer version of Entity Framework or something like that?

Comment: The EF part is unrelated, we just have a bunch of classes and are using reflection to get them. These are not nested classes in our source, I don't understand why they would now be compiled as such.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Well, they look like generated classes. Maybe some anonymous type, or a dynamic proxy? Maybe you are capturing the type of a closure, rather than its contents? It's hard to tell without a better example.

Comment: There's nothing like that; it's just two basic classes. I've edited two files in; one works normally, the other does not. There's nothing special that I can see.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny That's weird. Could it perhaps be that the "same" class is there twice, once with the normal name and once as a nested class that also extends `DbMigration`? Are you using some code obfuscator or something like that?